# How do I add a 'wrap' element to some asp tablerow elements in an ascx file so that I can hide/show them all with my vb code file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working with an older Server 2003 system and trying to create a new web form, based on other existing forms, which all follow certain conventions. (I'm guessing they were made with visual studio orignaly, but I'm not using this.) I'm not very fermiliar with asp/vb at all, I'm more of a PHP person, so I probably don't know the correct terms for lot a lot of the below.

I have an ascx file that contains my asp front end stuff in it. The main body has an asp table which is used when submitted the form to a database and sending it via email.

```
<asp:Table ID="inputTable" runat="server" CssClass="inputTable">
 /stuff here
</asp:Table>
```

This contains various asp table rows like so:

```
<asp:TableRow id="someid" visible="false">
    <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="LeftColumn">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Some Field Label here"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txt_somefield" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="You must select an answer"> *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </asp:TableHeaderCell>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="RightColumn">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_somefield" MaxLength="32" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Some of these will be text fields, others drop downs etc.

I want to be able to 'group' several of these fields together so I can then use by code file (asxc.vb) to then do something like

```
    Protected Sub ddl_someotherid_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl_someotherid.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ddl_someotherid.SelectedValue.Contains("Yes") Then
            somecollectionoffields.Visible = False
        Else if ddl_someotherid.SelectedValue.Contains("No") Then 
            somecollectionoffields.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

If I try to put normal html elements in my asp file among the  tags, then I will get an error such as `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRowCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow'. 'div' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.`

So I understand that I need some kind of asp tag there instead. I'm looking for something that when the asp engine in the web server parses it, it comes out as something that will not mess up the html table the asp has generated, but can be used to hide/show several form elements based on the choices made in other drop down elements above in the form. (I understand the putting a div in between table rows in normal HTML would not be correct, it was just the last tag I tried before posting this.)

If this were PHP, I could just 'interupt' the HTML table with a PHP tag, do my calculations to determine if the set of fields should be shown, then close the tag, but I don't know how to do this in asp/vb.

I did do some searching and found some slightly different questions that shows a asp tag called a panel using something like `<asp:panel>` but this results in a similar error to above, just telling me that this is not allowed also.

I don't really want to close the overall `<asp Table>` tag to do this, because this is used to grab the form contents to put it in an email, in the vb file and I don't know how to re-write that to compensate.

Comment: You need to learn asp.net first if you want to use it. There is not much difference between any server side language like PHP if you look on scripting part. `<asp:` tags are server side tags means you can get value on code behind. In PHP you get the posted data i.e. the control of type `input` with the name property of the control. In asp.net you get values by id (generally).

Comment: One more thing the asp controls also render as html controls on browser.

Comment: I understand that as a general concept, but I would prefer to learn by doing, and I'm sure I can work out another way of getting my end goal with this, but it might just be more longwinded. I'm happy to googe and try examples, but at this point I don't even know what the 'thing' I'm looking for is called to search for examples to lean from. An asp element? an asp control? What type of control? Does the thing I am asking for even exist or do I need to do it completely differently? Even if somsone can't answer the question fully, I would appreciate the background info to find the answer myself.

Comment: There is a server control (`<asp:`) corresponding to every html control. You need to find that control. You can also use the html controls with `runat='server' id ='ctlid'` and get it's value in code behind file(aspx.cs). I would also suggest to use mvc rather than plain asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, शेखर has sort of helped me come to the realisation that I needed with his comment that

> There is a server control (<asp:) corresponding to every html control.

Once I realised that all these asp: tags are just proxy's for actual html tags I realised that the asp parser is just trying to protect me from my own stupidity in creating invalid HTML at the other end. You cannot break up a table by enclosing some of it in a div in HTML, so asp won't let me do it either. I just needed to nestle one table inside another then show and hide the nestled one to achieve what I wanted. It was never about the vb side of things or the more advanced asp stuff.

So like this:

```
        <asp:TableRow id="someid" visible="false">
            <asp:TableHeaderCell >
                <asp:Table ID="subinputTable" runat="server" CssClass="subinputTable">
                    <asp:TableRow id="testfield1" >
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="LeftColumn">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Test Field 1"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="txt_test1" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="You must fill in this field"> *</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        <asp:TableCell CssClass="RightColumn">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_test1" MaxLength="32" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
```

This then works just fine. I can't promice it's the best or most elegant solution, but it's what I was looking for.